# when i change the folders name, some HTML functions start working

Tags: html, file, directory, filenames, subdirectory

Im doing a project and this page is a filter search, i wanted to maintain the same folder name that i was already using, but i dont know for what reason if the folder name is `paineis`(the name that i've been using previously),`style="display: none;"` starts showing up: https://imgur.com/a/Wfkw1sZ but if i change the of the folder to `paineis2`, for example, the filter parts starts showing up: https://imgur.com/a/cG7tLeU ,i also wanted to maintain the folder name as `paineis` for the sake of not needing to analyse all the others folders of the project and change the reference to another folder name.